# Least power of $x$ so that $y$ divides $x$

Tags: abstract-algebra, discrete-mathematics

How do I find the least $z$ to satisfy, $$y \mid x^z$$

I have tried keep dividing $y$ with the GCD($x$,$y$) until $y \mid x$ and adding $z$ by $1$ (starting from $1$), but turns out it's too slow.

Comment: Decompose both into prime factors. If *y* has at least one such factor that is missing from *x*, then *y* will divide no power of *x*. Otherwise, *z* has to be the smallest number so that $z\cdot a_k\ge b_k$ for all *k*, where $x=\displaystyle\prod_{k=1}^n(p_k)^{a_k}$ and $y=\displaystyle\prod_{k=1}^n(p_k)^{b_k}$

Comment: I wanted to try that, but the $x$ and $y$ is huge (up to $2^{64}$); and decomposing to prime factors consumes time.

Comment: There's really no other way. Use [elliptic curve methods](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenstra_elliptic_curve_factorization), like the one on [this](http://www.alpertron.com.ar/ECM.HTM) site. As you can see, it's pretty quick. A slightly better one, given the fact that $2^{64}$ has only $20$ digits, which is much less then $100$ digits, would be the one employing [quadratic sieves](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_sieve). Hope this helps.

Comment: That's new to me. I'll try to use this. Thank you.